# Numpy irregular samples (with replacement) of nonzero indices in each row

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to generate bootstrap samples of each row's nonzero indices. E.g. for this array:

```
m = np.array([[1,1,0,0], [1,1,0,1]])
```

I want to select two indices from the first row, and three from the second, with replacement. The non-vectorized solution is a for loop over the rows:

```
for row in m:
  idx = np.nonzero(row)[0]
  boot_idx = np.random.choice(idx, len(idx), replace=True)
  print(boot_idx)
```

To clarify the need, the array `m` is actually a mask of a 3D tensor, and I want to take bootstrap averages of that tensor based on the indices selected here.

Comment: which is the desired output's format?

Comment: the output format of `np.where` would work fine

Comment: which `np.where`??

Answer (score 0):

If speed is the concern, you could use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
@nb.njit
def func(m):
    for row in m:
        idx = np.nonzero(row)[0]
        boot_idx = np.random.choice(idx, len(idx), replace=True)
    return #return what you want
```

This results in significant speed increases:

```
def func_op(m):
    for row in m:
        idx = np.nonzero(row)[0]
        boot_idx = np.random.choice(idx, len(idx), replace=True)
    return
```

```
func(m) #Run once to JIT
%timeit func(m)
%timeit func_op(m)
```

Output:

```
706 ns ± 2.47 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
30.2 µs ± 859 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```